# gunicorn y docker-compose ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_busqueda'

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

ando teniendo el siguiente error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_busqueda' cuando intento crear y levantar la img con docker-compose y gunicorn.
la imagen la crear bien, sin errores pero a la hora de levantarla solo la db levanta. Ejecutando
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose-prod.yml up -d --build (ya que tengo dos compose, leyendo la docu entendi que es asi).

Mi docker-compose-prod.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn app_busqueda.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

La estructura del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el mensaje de error :

```
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
web_1  |     worker.init_process()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
web_1  |     self.load_wsgi()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
web_1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
web_1  |     self.callable = self.load()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
web_1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
web_1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
web_1  |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_busqueda'
```

Comment: ¿Qué contiene el Dockerfile?

Comment: Aca te dejo lo que actualmente contiene el Dockerfile.prod en un pastebin, https://pastebin.com/raw/p8vuZgwy

Answer (score 1):

Usando el comando `--pythonpath` y diciendole a gunicorn donde buscar basicamente

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --pythonpath app app_busqueda.wsgi:application
```

Comment: No termino de entender el motivo por el que en el manual no indica el parámetro `--pythonpath`. A mi también me solucionó el error.